# How to Populate JComboBox from ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jcombobox

I am trying to fetch some values from the MySQL database to `JComboBox` using `ArrayList` and `DefaultComboBoxModel` to avoid fetching duplicate values. Because JComboBox keeps filling the same values again and again to the JComboBox when I called the method to fetch values.

Currently, when the following code runs combo box is showing values like these,

> sometext@24084,
>   sometext@716a1

Here is my code,

```
public static void loadAll(JComboBox comboBox) {
        try {
            ArrayList<Combo> comboList = ComboBoxController.getComboType();
            DefaultComboBoxModel dtm = (DefaultComboBoxModel)comboBox.getModel();

            for (Combo combo : comboList) {
                Object[] rowData = {combo.getComboType()};
                dtm.addElement(rowData);
            }
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(AllComboBoxMethod.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

And Fetch Method,

```
int itemCount = combo.getItemCount(); 

for(int i = 1; i < itemCount; i++) { 
    combo.removeItemAt(0); 
}

String sql = "SELECT * FROM combo_type";
dbConnection = DbConnection.getInstance();
con = dbConnection.getConnection();
stm = con.createStatement();
rst = stm.executeQuery(sql);

ArrayList<Combo> comboList = new ArrayList();
while(rst.next()) {
     comboList.add(new Combo(rst.getString(2)));
}
return comboList;
```

So what I'm doing wrong? Is this the only way to avoid fetching duplicate values? I tried `comboBox.removeAllItems()` earlier (before adding this code) and then fetch the values. But it gives me `NullPointerException` some times. So how can I fix this?

Comment: Could you clarify which problem you need to solve? Is it only for the String representation?

Comment: @LppEdd Mainly, I need to avoid fetching duplicate values when calling the JComboBox fetch method again and again.

Comment: Where is this "fetch" method?

Comment: @LppEdd I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
sometext@716a1
```

is the unique identifier/memory address of a concrete class instance.
You're seeing that because you haven't correctly overridden the

```
public String toString();
```

method, for the `Combo` class.

---

Also, `DefaultComboBoxModel` is a generic enabled class

```
DefaultComboBoxModel<E>
```

so why are you using a raw instance?
You should be dealing with

```
DefaultComboBoxModel<Combo>
```

instead. Which means you could do

```
for (final Combo combo : comboList) {
   dtm.addElement(combo);
}
```

---

Try with

```
public static void loadAll(final JComboBox comboBox) {
    try {
        final List<Combo> comboList = ComboBoxController.getComboType();
        final DefaultComboBoxModel dtm = (DefaultComboBoxModel) comboBox.getModel();

        dtm.removeAllItems();

        for (final Combo combo : comboList) {
            dtm.addElement(combo.getComboType());
        }
    } catch (final SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AllComboBoxMethod.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

---

```
int itemCount = combo.getItemCount();

for (int i = itemCount - 1; i >= 0; i++) { 
   combo.removeItemAt(0); 
}
```

Comment: isn't this a duplicate of a gabillion similar questions?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels mmmh I'm trying to understand if he's trying to solve only a "toString" problem or if there is more.

Comment: I tried `overriding toString` method. It shows me `Java.Lang.Object;@546` like this.

Comment: @HasithaMJayawardana Is it showing it like [Ljava.lang.Object;@60438a68 ? With an [L in front?

Comment: @LppEdd Yes L is there

Comment: @HasithaMJayawardana try with the code I posted in my answer.

Comment: @LppEdd `dtm.removeAllItems();` gives me `NullPointerException` some times.

Comment: @HasithaMJayawardana because you haven't associated a ComboBoxModel to the JComboBox, so when you retrieve it, it's null

Comment: @LppEdd How can I do that? Because I need to keep a default value.

Comment: @HasithaMJayawardana using JComboBox constructor, or using setModel. See documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html

Comment: is there any way to keep the first element and remove all others? I have tried with a `for loop`. But didn't work.

Comment: @HasithaMJayawardana use a for loop which has an index starting at 1, and use DefaultComboBoxModel#removeElementAt method, or JComboBox#removeItemAt

Comment: @LppEdd I tried that and didn't work. I tried this `int itemCount = combo.getItemCount();

for(int i = 1; i < itemCount; i++) {
    combo.removeItemAt(0);
}`

Comment: @HasithaMJayawardana wait, I'll go to have dinner then we can see better. Post all your updated code